Suppose we observe a photon, what can we measure about it?
I guess we can measure spin, momentum, kinetic energy, position, time, wavelength, e.g., (I don't know much about this), are there other properties?
How many degrees of freedom are there?
Because for example, (momentum, energy, wavelength) has only 1 degree of freedom I think (I don't know much about this) since they are related.
And how many of these properties can we measure in one observation?

First, you can measure the fact that the photon is there, for example a "click" in a Geiger counter. This might seem a little philosophical, but many experiments boil down to counting photons.
Second, you can measure the energy of the photon $E$. This is related to its total momentum $p$ by $E=pc$ (where $c$ is the speed of light), and frequency $f$ and wavelength $\lambda$ by $E=hf$ and $\lambda f = c$.
Third, you can measure the direction of the momentum of the photon.
Finally, you can measure the spin state of a photon. You can do this in different bases; common bases are to look at the linear polarization of a photon along some axis ("spin up" vs "spin down"), or circular polarization ("right circularly polarized" vs left circularly polarized").
A photon has two degrees of freedom, corresponding to two spin degrees of freedom, which you can think of as the spin along the two axes perpendicular to the direction of motion of the photon.
Not all experiments will measure all these properties. The properties are roughly in order of how difficult they are to measure. Many experiments (eg of radioactive decay) will just look to count photons above a threshold energy, without worrying too much about the precise energy, direction, or polarization state. On the other hand, if you have seen pictures of the LHC, the inner part of the huge ring that you see are a set of electromagetic calorimeters, which measure the energy and momenta of the photons that leave a scattering event (at least, the "transverse" energy and momenta perpendicular to the beam). Meanwhile, for detailed measurements of entanglement of photons, it is very important to measure the spin degrees of freedom of the photon, since a lot of the interesting entanglement effects they are trying to measure boil down to correlating outcomes of measurements of the spin of entangled photons along different axes.

Presence of a photon, and then 4 degrees of freedom? momentum vector, position, spin, polarization? Is presence the t in E/t? If we measure the pair E/t do we also have a measurement for p/x? Is there a pairing like that for spin/polarization? Can we measure momentum and spin of the same photon? How does that all work in practice? And thanks for the answer so far.

Arrival time is an observable, although it becomes difficult to define it precisely in quantum mechanics, so it only really makes sense up to some level of precision. You cannot measure both $E$ and $t$, or $p$ and $x$, arbitrarily precisely at the same time due to the uncertainty principle. Similarly the components of angular momentum obey an uncertainty principle as described in quantum mechanics texts. However, momentum and spin do not have an uncertainty principle so you can measure momentum and spin simultaneously.

I'm not sure what you mean by "how does that all work in practice," but if you mean "how are different properties of photons measured in a lab," that's a good question and I've given some hints in my answer, but I'm not an experimentalist and I think that should be asked as a separate question. Also be aware there are multiple ways to measure each property and which one is appropriate depends on the situation, so you should probably do some research before coming back with a more specific "how" question if that is what you are interested in.
